# Run Postgres migration script

Tags: heroku, postgres

I'm currently running a Dockerized NodeJS application that's using Postgres. The Postgres database url is coming as an environment variable, as set by Heroku. While this works great inside my container, I'm wondering how I should go ahead about running database migrations.

At which stage should I be doing this? I suppose I can't do this as part of my docker build process, as this happens outside of the Heroku environment.

What's the correct process for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new heroku.yml preview:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-yml-build-manifest

You'll need to move to that in order to have release phase support with containers.

You can add this to heroku.yml:

```
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - migrateScriptYoureUsing
```

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-builds-heroku-yml#release-release-phase

Alternatively, you can do this by pushing a `release` image. That image will be used as the release phase one whenever any process type is deployed.